# Use Cell Value (Contains periods & Apastrophe) In Hyperlink Address

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2013

I want to take the value from cell A2 and use it as the hyperlink address with my VBA.  For example, let's say that cell A2 has a value of Pink, I want to link to worksheet Pink!A1.  Issue I have is that I get an error of

> Syntax error

How should this be altered in order to be valid syntax?

```
Dim lr As Long, i As Long
lr = Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
For i = 2 To lr
  ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Selection, Address:="", SubAddress:=Cells(i, 2).Value"!A1"
Next i
```

**EDIT**
For clarity let me add that I want the link to be placed in Column O, with the current cell value of Column O, but the worksheet to link to should be the value of column B.

**EDIT 2**
Using thte syntax suggested by @Jeremy has gotten me closer and I am at this point, where I found the issue was any special symbol (i.e. a comma, period, hyphen etc) must be enclosed with a single quote.  Which leaves my syntax at the below, but get an error

> Invalid Procedure call or argument

I think I am close to having this perfect but not quite there:

```
Function TakeTwo()
Dim lr As Long, i As Long
Dim sSheet As String
Dim ws As Worksheet

Set ws = ActiveSheet
lr = Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
For i = 2 To lr
  If ws.Cells(i, 2).Value Like "*,*" Or ws.Cells(i, 2).Value Like "*'*" Or ws.Cells(i, 2).Value Like "*&*" Or ws.Cells(i, 2).Value Like "*-*" Or ws.Cells(i, 2).Value Like "*.*" Then
    ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=ws.Cells(i, 15), Address:="", SubAddress:="'" & ws.Cells(i, 2).Value & "'!A1", TextToDisplay:=ws.Cells(i, 15)
  Else
    ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=ws.Cells(i, 15), Address:="", SubAddress:=ws.Cells(i, 2).Value & "!A1", TextToDisplay:=ws.Cells(i, 15)
  End If
Next i
ws.Activate
End Function
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shooting without trying it:
Change it to this:

```
  ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Selection, Address:="", SubAddress:=Cells(i, 2).Value & "!A1"
```

Comment: That got it.  One additional ? - how can I keep the cell text what it is currently and not change it to the value of Cells(i,2)

Comment: Add additional argument -  TextToDisplay:="something". https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff822490.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
Dim lr As Long, i As Long
Dim sSheet As String
Dim ws As Worksheet

Set ws = ActiveSheet
lr = Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
For i = 2 To lr
    ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=ws.Cells(i, 15), Address:="", SubAddress:=ws.Cells(i, 2).Value & "!A1", TextToDisplay:=ws.Cells(i, 15)
Next i
ws.Activate
```

Comment: This puts the hyperlink in column B - I want the hyperlink to be in column O, but have the Address be the name in column B.

Comment: Updated - should do what you want now

Comment: I get an error of invalid procedure call or argument.  On the ActiveSheet... line

Comment: @SmallFriesBigGuys I thought you wanted to keep the text in column o but you obviously don't have text there.. I've updated again

Comment: if I click the newly created hyperlink I get an error of reference is not valid.  If I hover over the hyperlink, it shows the correct naming convention Workbookname.xlsx - Worksheetname!A1 - Click once to follow - Click and hold to select cell.

Comment: I assume you won't actually have these sheets created? I've included a line to create these above

Comment: No the sheets already exist.  That's why I was confused that it was saying invalid reference.  And if I compare the worksheet name to the value in the cell in column B they are an exact match.

Comment: The name must be different (that's the only thing it could be) because I've checked and it's fine for me - Maybe different case or spaces before or after the sheet names in column B (or the sheet names themselves)

Comment: It appears the hyperlink is not properly being created.  For example, if I right click the cell and say Edit Hyperlink, the tab 'Place in this Document' is selected, but a worksheet name is not selected.  If I manually add the worksheet name, the hyperlink then becomes clicakble.

Comment: @SmallFriesBigGuys That's what `SubAddress:=ws.Cells(i, 2).Value & "!A1"` does.. it works fine for me

Comment: I see what the diff is, if I have no text in column O it works.  My workbook has a numeric value in column O that I want to keep, just make it link to the worksheet name contained in column B

Comment: Ok.. one last time!

Comment: Also, it will give me the invalid reference error if the value in column B contains a ".", a "," a single quote " ' "

Comment: Updated syntax throws an error of Invalid Procedure call or argument